# Is Top Reviewer Today count based on UTC day?

Tags: support, review-stats

Is the count displayed under *Top Reviewers Today* section of the [review stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) based on a UTC day?

I did a review *21 hours* ago and another *3 hours* ago but my count of reviews done today is 1 (instead of 2).

> [image]

---

> [image]

Same is observed in the *reopen review queue*. I did a review *21 hours* ago and none today, my stats show 0 reviews under the *Today* list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 'today' is the UTC day, the numbers reset every night at 00:00 UTC.

21 hours ago was yesterday.